# Dependency Management in Android

Tags: android, dependencies, dependency-management

I am currently working on an Android project where we have taken an approach of building maven libraries for some of our resuable feature modules. Currently, I have stumbled on a problem of conflicting versions of the same dependency (ex compose-ui) in multiple modules

I know this is not a new problem but I am interested to hear some real life epxeriences on approaches to solve this issue